# Static lightning is not calculated: "Objects have different materials"

Tags: unity-game-engine, mesh

I have 4 meshes in my scene as such

[image]

These GameObjects are essentially 4 cubes and a plane like so

[image]

For testing purposes, I wanted to see if I understood static batching by trying it out on these GameObjects. They have been marked as static and they share the same material, which was drag and dropped. However, the frame debugger tells me that they aren't batched because `Objects have different materials`. Why is that so even though I drag and dropped the materials onto the objects?

Edit:
The necessary static flags have been set

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Have you set up static flags correctly?

[image]

Comment: Try run the scene. Static batching does not working in edit mode.

Comment: I tried running it in the editor but the frame debugger still tells me that they aren't batching

Comment: I insist you to press "play" button :D In edit mode Unity may perform only dynamic batching.

Comment: By running it in the editor, I meant that I tried to run the app i.e. I pressed play